# Mostra postagens de uma Tag em uma pagina Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Estou tentando organiza meus posts com base nas tag de cada artigo. Exemplo? Carros, casas, a, b, c ... e assim por diante.

Encontrei esse site que parece fazer issso perfeitamente:

http://punchsub.net/#lista-de-animes/nome/todos/1

No exemplo do site, as postagens estão separadas por letra.

Como eu posso fazer algo semelhante usando o Wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Este procedimento encontra as tags que tem posts associados à elas, e monta uma lista baseada na primeira letra:

```
$list = '';
$tags = get_terms( 'post_tag' );
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
    }
    if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<h2>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h2>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $url = attribute_escape( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) );
                $count = intval( $tag->count );
                $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
                $list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a> (' . $count . ')</li>';
                }
            $list .= "\n\t" . '</li>';
        }
    }
}else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Nenhuma Tag foi encontrada</p>';
```

A partir daí, fica a seu critério como chamar o método, ou mesmo se quer usar este processo dessa maneira. No meio do código tem bastante coisas que podem ser reduzidas, mas a ideia é basicamente essa. Basta você dar um `print ($list)` que você tem acesso à tudo.